# Remove duplicate keys from both arrays using php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove duplicate keys from both arrays.

My code is

```
$arr1[22068] = array('ID' => 22068);
$arr1[22067] = array('ID' => 22067);
$arr2[22068] = array('ID' => 22068);
$arr2[22066] = array('ID' => 22066);

$arr = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);

var_dump($arr); //It outputs null.
```

The final array should look like this--

```
$arr[22066] = array('ID' => 22066);
$arr[22067] = array('ID' => 22067);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I undertand for 22068, but why 22066 ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I have updated the post. I want the key 22068 to be removed from both array and produce a new array.

Comment: easy with a `foreach()` loop, but maybe some one will answer with a sexier  solution

Comment: I don't know the language, but could the problem involve that 1 - 1 = 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_diff_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) is what you want.

```
$arr1[22068] = array('ID' => 22068);
$arr1[22067] = array('ID' => 22067);
$arr2[22068] = array('ID' => 22068);
$arr2[22066] = array('ID' => 22066);

// Get elements of array 1 which are not present in array 2
$unique_1 = array_diff_key($arr1, $arr2);

// Get elements of array 2 which are not present in array 1
$unique_2 = array_diff_key($arr2, $arr1);

// Merge unique values
$unique = $unique_1 + $unique_2;
```

Comment: you should use `$unique = $unique_1 + $unique_2;` to preserve original numeric keys. `array_merge` will reset numeric  keys `22067` and `22066` to `0` and `1`

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot for the solution and explanation too.

Comment: @krlv Thanks for pointing this out. I was missing the original key. Now it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

So array_diff will give you what's different in array1 vs array2, and will NOT work on multi-dimensional arrays. You can switch to array_key_diff, however, you'll run into a similar issue:

```
$arr1[22068] = array('ID' => 22068);
$arr1[22067] = array('ID' => 22067);
$arr2[22068] = array('ID' => 22068);
$arr2[22066] = array('ID' => 22066);

$arr = array_diff_key($arr1, $arr2);

var_dump($arr); //It outputs array(1) {[22067]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> int(22067) } }
```

I'm not aware of a "magic" solution with the differences, however, you do have options, you can take the code above and add an extra line for:

```
$arr2 = array_diff_key($arr2, $arr1);
var_dump($arr2)
```

then merge $arr and $arr2, or you can just write a loop going through and comparing each item. Depending on size, scope, readability, etc will depend on the actual set

Comment: Thanks for your help too.